# WP audio playlist width

Tags: audio, playlist

How can I adjust the width on the WP audio playlist if I'm using the following:

```
[wpse_playlist tracknumbers="false" images="false" artist="false"]
   [wpse_trac title="Track1'" src="www.mypage.com/audio/track1.mp3]
   [wpse_trac title="Track2'" src="www.mypage.com/audio/track2.mp3]
   [wpse_trac title="Track3'" src="www.mypage.com/audio/track3.mp3]
[/wpse_playlist]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
    <div style="float:left;width:50%;">
    <div style="padding-right:10px;">

    [playlist images="false" artists="false" ids="639,640,641"]
    </div></div>

    <div style="float:right;width:50%;">
    <div style="padding-left:10px;">

    [playlist images="false" artists="false" ids="639,640,641"]
    </div></div>

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Best,